# A function that returns email addresses from a list of strings in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I need to create a function which returns email addresses from a list of strings. I have done this successfully with the following code:

```
def myfunction(bigstring):
    str = ' '.join(bigstring)
    my_string = str
    str1 = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', my_string)
    return str1
```

However when I run the following sample:

```
emails = ['John Kennedy <jk123@gmail.com> or <johnk123@hotmail.com>','Adam Hartley <ah123@yahoo.com>','Ben Saunders <benji@live.co.uk>']
myfunction(emails)
```

I get the output:

```
['jk123@gmail.com', 'johnk123@hotmail.com', 'ah123@yahoo.com', 'benji@live.co.uk']
```

However i would like the following output, but I am not sure how to do so without messing up my code:

```
[['jk123@gmail.com', johnk123@hotmail.com'], ['ah123@yahoo.com'], ['benji@live.co.uk']]
```

I need to return a list within a list as shown by the desired output.

Comment: Well, maybe don't join the emails list in the first place?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use `str` as a variable name, its already a built in keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to join the initial array of email containing strings.

```
def my_function(str_array):
    return [re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', s) for s in str_array]

emails = ['John Kennedy <jk123@gmail.com> or <johnk123@hotmail.com>','Adam Hartley <ah123@yahoo.com>','Ben Saunders <benji@live.co.uk>']

my_function(emails)
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract emails in each list item:

```
import re

emails = ['John Kennedy <jk123@gmail.com> or <johnk123@hotmail.com>','Adam Hartley <ah123@yahoo.com>','Ben Saunders <benji@live.co.uk>']
def myfunction(bigstring):
    result = []
    for s in bigstring:
        result.append(re.findall(r'[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+', s))
    return result

print(myfunction(emails))
# => [['jk123@gmail.com', 'johnk123@hotmail.com'], ['ah123@yahoo.com'], ['benji@live.co.uk']]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/zdMpUk).

Actually, `bigstring` is a bad name here as it is a list. Consider renaming to, say, `my_list` or something.

As for the regex, you do not need to escape dots inside character classes.

Answer (score 1):

Dont join the whole string in function and pass the string one by one by iteration like this

```
import re
def myfunction(bigstring):
    return  re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', bigstring)

emails = ['John Kennedy <jk123@gmail.com> or <johnk123@hotmail.com>','Adam Hartley <ah123@yahoo.com>','Ben Saunders <benji@live.co.uk>']


output = []
for emailstring in emails:
    output.append((myfunction(emailstring)))
print(output)
```

using **list comprehension**

```
output = [ myfunction(email) for email in emails ]
print(output)
```

using **map**

```
print(map(myfunction,emails))
```

**Output**

```
[['jk123@gmail.com', 'johnk123@hotmail.com'], ['ah123@yahoo.com'], ['benji@live.co.uk']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def myfunction(bigstring):
    #str = ' '.join(bigstring)
    #my_string = str
    str1 = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', bigstring)
    return str1

import re
output=[]
emails = ['John Kennedy <jk123@gmail.com> or <johnk123@hotmail.com>','Adam Hartley <ah123@yahoo.com>','Ben Saunders <benji@live.co.uk>']
for item in emails:
    output.append(myfunction(item))

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def myfunction(bstr):
        #str = ' '.join(bstr)
        #my_string = str
        str1 = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', bstr)
        return str1
    import re
    output=[]
    emails = ['John Kennedy <jk123@gmail.com> or <johnk123@hotmail.com>','Adam 
              Hartley <ah123@yahoo.com>','Ben Saunders <benji@live.co.uk>']
     for item in emails:
        output.append(myfunction(item))
```